# Is RecyclerView refreshed when AlertDialog's positive button gets pressed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My MainActivity has a `RecyclerView` adapter, and data to this RecyclerView is added through a AlertDialog which passes the entered text to the MainActivity. The recycler view gets refreshed somehow when the positive button in the dialog is pressed even though I never call notifyItemInserted() or notifyDatasetChange() after passing the new input. I want to know how this happens, my guess is the recyclerview is somehow refreshed after the positive button is pressed in the dialog box

Custom AlertDialog Code:

```
 public class CustomDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
        OnNoteAddedListener onNoteAddedListener;

    public interface OnNoteAddedListener {
        public void onClick(String note);
    }

    public CustomDialog(OnNoteAddedListener onNoteAddedListener) {
        this.onNoteAddedListener = onNoteAddedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box, null);
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(dialogLayout).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                EditText addNote = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
                String note = addNote.getText().toString();
                onNoteAddedListener.onClick(note);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                CustomDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Adapter code:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private List<String> notesList;
    private Context mContext;
    private SendPositionConnector sendPositionConnector;
public interface SendPositionConnector
{
    public void sendPosition(int position);
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> notesList, Context mContext)
{
    this.notesList = notesList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.sendPositionConnector = (MainActivity)mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHandler: called");
    viewHolder.noteContent.setText(notesList.get(position));
    viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLongClick: long clicked on");
            sendPositionConnector.sendPosition(position);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return notesList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView noteContent;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    ImageView bullet;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        bullet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bullet);
        noteContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_content);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    }
}
}
```

Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.SendPositionConnector
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private List<String> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private int position;
    public AgentAsyncTask agentAsyncTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    agentAsyncTask = new AgentAsyncTask(notesList, getApplicationContext(), true, new AgentAsyncTask.OnRead(){
        @Override
        public void onRead(List<String> notesList)
        {
            if(!notesList.isEmpty())
                MainActivity.this.notesList = notesList;
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(notesList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    agentAsyncTask.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.add_note:
            showDialogBox(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    new AgentAsyncTask(notesList, getApplicationContext(), false, new AgentAsyncTask.OnRead(){
        @Override
        public void onRead(List<String> notesList)
        {
            if(!notesList.isEmpty())
                MainActivity.this.notesList = notesList;
        }
    }).execute();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

private boolean showDialogBox(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    AppCompatDialogFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialog(new CustomDialog.OnNoteAddedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(String note)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+ note);
            notesList.add(note);
        }
    });
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Adding");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    switch(menuItem.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.delete:
            notesList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, notesList.size());
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void sendPosition(int position)
{
    this.position = position;
}

private static class AgentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>
{
    private List<String> notesList;
    private boolean flag;
    OnRead onRead;
    Context context;
    AppDataBase dataBase;
    private static final String TAG = "AgentAsyncTask";
    public interface OnRead
    {
        public void onRead(List<String> notesList);
    }
    private AgentAsyncTask(List<String> notesList,Context context,boolean flag, OnRead onRead)
    {
        this.notesList = notesList;
        this.onRead = onRead;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        dataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDataBase.class, "database-name").build();
        if(!flag)
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
            String json = gson.toJson(notesList, type);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+json);
            Notes notes = new Notes();
            notes.setNoteContent(json);
            notes.setUid(1);
            dataBase.notesDao().insertNotes(notes);
            return notesList;
        }
        else
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String notesListContent = dataBase.notesDao().getNotes();
            if(dataBase.notesDao().getCount() != 0)
            {
                notesList = gson.fromJson(notesListContent, new TypeToken<List<String>>()
                {
                }.getType());
            }
            else
            {
                return notesList;
            }
            return notesList;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> notesList)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(notesList);
        if(flag)
            onRead.onRead(notesList);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add your adapter and mainactivity code

Comment: @prashant17 i want to know if recyclerview in an activity is refreshed when positive button is pressed in a dialog box and if yes how does this happen. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add that code for us to tell you that.

Comment: @DavidLiu Added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably happening is that when the dialog returns, it causes a re-layout of the RecyclerView, which rebinds the views. This is prone to bugs though, since it may not have updated the recycler about stuff like the list length or item view types, etc, so the appropriate `notify` method should always be used.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the text from the dialog to main activity after pressing the positive button.
Append your list with that new text that you are passing to adapter and call method

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I know that we need to call this method, but it is working without calling that method. I want to know why and how it’s working.

Comment: If you don't call this method then you'll only *crash* if you *remove* items. You just won't be showing some item on some index on insert

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is not happening, it is refreshing somehow, can u plz look at my code and tell me how?